# System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include : Object reference not set to an instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Following is my query

```
 Details _details = _db.Details
                    .Include(x => x.Location)
                    .Where(x => x.DetailType.Equals("ClientID") && x.DetailValue.Equals(5))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Sometimes this query throws the following exception

```
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.,
  StackTrace:    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.Include(String path)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T](IQueryable`1 source, String path)
   at System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include[T,TProperty](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 path)
```

From the message, I understand that its null reference exception. Trying to figure out whats null. Is it _db(database context), or the result from the Where clause or the link between Details and Location.

Comment: Have you considered using `==` rather than `Equals` (likely won't help with your current issue)?

Comment: `or the result from the Where clause or the link between Details and Location.` Split the code up to do one thing at a time (not all in one line of code).

Comment: Check the `Location` member of the entity class. Is it property (and not field for instance)? Is it `public`? Is it mapped as navigation property in the model?

Comment: Hi @mjwills, == or Equals didnt make any difference.

Comment: @IvanStoev yeah, Location is a property. Virtual Property.

Answer (score 1):

Next time you ask a question, consider to give us the relevant part of your `Detail` class. Now we have to guess the types.

Apparently you have a table of `Details` (`IQueryable<Detail>`),
where every `Detail` has at least properties `Location`, `DetailType` and `DetailValue`.

`DetailType` seems to be a string, `DetailValue` seems to be some kind of number.

You want to fetch (some properties or) all `Details` that have a `DetailType` equal to "ClientId" and a `DetailValue` equal to 5.

Are you sure that every `Detail` has a non-null `DetailType`? Is `DetailValue` a nullable type? Can it be that some returned `Details` are null?

I think this is the cause of the problem: some `Details` have a null `DetailType` or a null `DetailValue`.

```
var string requestedDetailType = "ClientId";
var result = _db.Details
    .Where(detail => detail.DetailType == requestedDetailType
                  && detail.DetailValue == 5)
    .Select(detail => new Detail
    {
        // Select only the Detail properties that you plan to use.
        Id = detail.Id,
        ...

        Location = new Location
        {
            // select the Location properties that you plan to use
            ...
        },
    });
```

If your framework doesn't allow `==`, consider to check on non-null before you use the value of the property:

```
.Where(detail => detail.DetailType != null
              && detail.DetailType == requestedDetailType
              && ...
```

or

```
.Where(detail => detail?.DetailType?.Equals(requestedDetailType) ?? false
              && ...
```

### optimization: use Select instead of Include

It seems there is a one-to-many relation between `Locations` and `Details`: Every `Location` has zero or more `Details`, every `Detail` has exactly one `Location`, namely the Location that the foreign key refers to.

If you query `Detail [10] with its Location`, then Detail[10] will have a foreign key, with a value, say [100] to its Location. This Location will have a primary key with a value [100].

Other way round: if you querye `Location[100] with its 2000 Details`, then every `Detail` will have a foreign key with a value 100. It would be a waste to send this same value 100 more than 2000 times.

> In a query (especially entity framework), always use Select, and select only the properties that you plan to use. Only use Include if you plan to update the included objects.

Certainly don't use Include do save you some typing!

By using Select you separate the format of your tables from the returned data. It gives you the freedom to change your database layout without users of your code having to change.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query is incorrect - load a single Details entity and its related location.

```
 Details _details = _db.Details
                    .Where(x => x.DetailType.Equals("ClientID") && x.DetailValue.Equals(5))
                    .Include(x => x.Location)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```